# Win32: capture handle to Display monitor

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I am currently developing an application that requires an `HDC` for each of the screens connected to the system.

I am currently using code like this:

```
std::vector<HDC> dcs;
HDC dcMain = ::GetDC(nullptr); // <-- don't understand this

::EnumDisplayMonitors(dcMain, nullptr, MONITORENUMPROC(&DisplayMonitorCallback), LPARAM(&dcs));
```

My callback is as follows:

```
BOOL DisplayMonitorCallback(const HMONITOR monitor, const HDC hdcMonitor, const LPRECT lprcMonitor, std::vector<HDC>& dcs)
{
    dcs.push_back(hdcMonitor);

    // here is where it gets weird!
    HBRUSH br = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 255, 0));

    auto rst = FillRect(hdcMonitor, lprcMonitor, br);

    // Process all monitors
    return TRUE;
}
```

Notice that I am currently rendering a green brush on each screen.  This works perfectly in *THIS* context (i.e. within the callback).

Now, the problem is, I am capturing those `HDC`s to use at a later time.

So a couple of lines later, I'm iterating over my `dcs` vector:

```
for (HDC dc : dcs)
{
    HBRUSH br = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 255, 0));

    RECT x = { 100, 100, 500, 500 };        

    auto rst = FillRect(dc, &x, br);

    printf("%d", rst);
}
```

So, my questions are:

1. for the `dcMain`, I have to pass this in, is this the good way to get one?
2. why does the rendering work in the callback, but does not work when I capture the `HDC`s and iterate over them later?

Comment: The documentation does not spell it out, but you can assume, given how similar enumeration functions work in other APIs, that the HDC given to each callback function is acquired by EnumDisplayMonitors() itself during the enumeration process and then immediately released when the callback returns; that is, it might only be safe to use that HDC during the callback function itself. But continuing that train of thought will lead us into XY problem territory, so: what are you trying to do that requires individual monitor HDCs?

Comment: @andlabs thanks, I need the HDC to instantiate a IDXGISurface1: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471345(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: That method returns the HDC associated with a IDXGISurface1; what are you using to actually create the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. yes, and this is mentioned in the [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162610.aspx) documentation:

   > To paint the entire virtual screen optimally for each display monitor, you can use code like this:
   >
   > ```
   > hdc = GetDC(NULL);
   > EnumDisplayMonitors(hdc, NULL, MyPaintScreenEnumProc, 0);
   > ReleaseDC(NULL, hdc);
   > ```
2. the `HDC`s are only valid inside of the callback, as @andlabs suggested.  And this makes sense, because an `HDC` has to be obtained and then released, but only `EnumDisplayMonitors()` knows **how** each `HDC` is obtained, and so only it knows **how** to release each one correctly.  Since there is no API function for releasing an enumerated `HDC`, this implies that the `HDC`s are not valid outside of the enumeration.

   MSDN tells you how to obtain an `HDC` for a given monitor:

   [HMONITOR and the Device Context](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144968.aspx)

   > Each physical display is represented by a monitor handle of type `HMONITOR`. A valid `HMONITOR` is guaranteed to be non-NULL. A physical display has the same `HMONITOR` as long as it is part of the desktop. When a `WM_DISPLAYCHANGE` message is sent, any monitor may be removed from the desktop and thus its `HMONITOR` becomes invalid or has its settings changed. Therefore, an application should check whether all `HMONITORS` are valid when this message is sent.
   >
   > Any function that returns a display device context (DC) normally returns a DC for the primary monitor. To obtain the DC for another monitor, use the `EnumDisplayMonitors` function. **Or, you can use the device name from the `GetMonitorInfo` function to create a DC with `CreateDC`**. However, if the function, such as `GetWindowDC` or `BeginPaint`, gets a DC for a window that spans more than one display, the DC will also span the two displays.

   For example:

   ```
   typedef std::vector<HDC> hdc_vector;

   BOOL CALLBACK DisplayMonitorCallback(HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData)
   {
       MONITORINFOEX mi = {0};
       mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
       if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi))
       {
           HDC dc = CreateDC(NULL, mi.szDevice, NULL, NULL);
           if (dc)
               reinterpret_cast<hdc_vector*>(dwData)->push_back(dc);
       }
       ...
       return TRUE;
   }
   ```

   ```
   hdc_vector dcs;

   EnumDisplayMonitors(dcMain, nullptr, DisplayMonitorCallback, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&dcs));

   ...

   for (HDC dc : dcs)
   {
       ...
   }

   ...

   for (HDC dc : dcs)
       DeleteDC(dc);
   ```

   Since you are clearly using C++11, I would suggest using `std::unique_ptr` for the memory management of the `HDC`s so you don't have to call `DeleteDC()` manually.  And I would use a lambda for the callback, and change the `std::vector` to a `std::map` (so you can lookup the `HDC` of any specific monitor when needed):

   ```
   typedef std::unique_ptr<std::remove_pointer<HDC>::type, decltype(::DeleteDC)> device_hdc;
   typedef std::map<HMONITOR, device_hdc> device_hdc_map;

   device_hdc_map dcs;

   EnumDisplayMonitors(dcMain, nullptr,
       [](HMONITOR hMonitor, HDC hdcMonitor, LPRECT lprcMonitor, LPARAM dwData) -> BOOL {
           MONITORINFOEX mi = {0};
           mi.cbSize = sizeof(mi);
           if (GetMonitorInfo(hMonitor, &mi))
           {
               HDC dc = CreateDC(NULL, mi.szDevice, NULL, NULL);
               if (dc)
                   (*reinterpret_cast<device_hdc_map*>(dwData))[hMonitor] = device_hdc(dc, &::DeleteDC);
           }
           ...
           return TRUE;
       },
       reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&dcs)
   );

   ...

   for (device_hdc_map::value_type &dc : dcs)
   {
       // use dc.second.get() (the actual HDC) as needed ...
   }
   ```